# Typescript. How to get enum item data as a type

Tags: typescript

I have an enum type, for example `Currency`. I cant to change it because it automatically builds on a graphql schema. I want to use it for my data, but I dont know how to do.

```
enum Currency {
  rub = 'RUB',
  usd = 'USD',
  eur = 'EUR',
}

const data: { currency: Currency[keyof typeof Currency] } = {
  currency: 'RUB',
};
```

**Errors**

```
TS2339: Property 'eur' does not exist on type 'Currency'.
TS2339: Property 'rub' does not exist on type 'Currency'.
TS2339: Property 'usd' does not exist on type 'Currency'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible to do exactly what you're trying to do but most likely, you'd want to do something like this:

```
const data: { currency: Currency } = {
  currency: Currency.rub,
};
```

This is how enums are typically used (by always explicitly referencing the enum when getting one of its values).

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right. I will accept you answer when the stackoverflow allows it